# Xcode making a popping sound whenever there is an error message

Tags: xcode, audio

New to Xcode and I think it keeps playing a popping sound whenever there is an error message. I can't find out if there isanyway to turn it off as its driving me crazy? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a Behavior. Run through everything in the Behaviors pref pane (there are a LOT of them) looking for places where the first checkbox (sound) is checked, and uncheck it. Seems unlikely, since there is no sound checked by default, but you never know.